# HTML5 Canvas overlay for Flash

Tags: html, flash, html5-canvas

Basically, I am trying to create an HTML5 canvas to overlay an embedded 3rd party flash application. I cannot set the flash's wmode as I have no control over the flash itself, I was wondering if it was possible to work around this, and position a canvas (or anything for that matter) visibly in front of the flash element.

I understand that this is probably not possible, but I would appreciate any feedback, even if it's just telling me that what I'm asking is impossible.

Comment: With normal elements that would be fine, but z-index/positioning doesn't allow something to be placed "in front" of Flash to my knowledge.